# How to change default naming convention for duplicate downloads

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, filenames

I found a similar question on this site, but it wasn't exactly a match and no one solved it.

I save and organize many pictures, everyday.  Most of them come in sets.  So I name the first picture "pictureM".  And I copy that name and then paste the name when it comes to saving the 2nd picture, but then I have also have to manually add a corresponding number.  i.e. "pictureM2".  In Firefox, if I don't add the number, a dialog pops up asking if I want to replace the "pictureM" with the current download.

What I would love for it to do is just save the picture, with no dialog or feedback, but add the sequential number automatically.  i.e. If "pictureM" already exists, the picture still saves as "pictureM2".  Then the next picture I try to save will auto save as "pictureM3", and so on.

If another browser does this, please inform me.  If another browser does this, but saves it in the format "pictureM (2)" or something funky like that, is there a way to change the formatting in browser settings?

Maybe it's not the browser at all, but my OS that does everything.  In that case, I am using Windows 7, 64 Bit.

Thanks

Comment: The format is of big concern.  I would like it to be "pictureM1" and "pictureM2", oppose to "pictureM_001" or "pictureM (2)".  I'm also not looking for a batch downloader.  I'm saving the pictures one at a time, to put things in the correct order.  I think, if anything exists to help me on this, it would be somewhere in a settings file for windows or firefox/chrome/etc.  I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-pt/firefox/addon/downthemall/ extension.

You're prompted if you want to overwrite the first time but you can select a dropdown option to remember the setting.

If your format must be met, this won't work for you, since it has the format "filename_001,filename_002" and i believe you can't change it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The format does matter, though.  Added more to my question to further delve into what I'm looking for.