# Custom File Naming Convention For Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

### Problem

- **Is it possible** to change **windows file saving convention format** so  that it will automatically include a date in front of the file name (or something custom) before it prompts me to save? 
  (I dare to ask if there is such a "smart file naming system" that can detect context and offer a suggestion on what to name it.)

Would it be better to batch rename files by appending the date created?

- [Batch Rename by Date Created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079757/rename-file-with-creation-date-time-in-windows-batch)

#### Research

I searched for a little while and the nearest I could find to this problem was these questions:

- [How to change default naming convention for duplicate downloads](https://superuser.com/questions/889917/how-to-change-default-naming-convention-for-duplicate-downloads)
- [File Name Convention](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55629/what-is-your-file-naming-convention-you-use-for-version-control)
- [Papers, articles, books etc. file naming conventions](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/9006/papers-articles-books-etc-file-naming-conventions)
- [file-naming-convention-ten-rules-best-practice](http://www.exadox.com/en/articles/file-naming-convention-ten-rules-best-practice)

### Motivation for Why I Want Better file naming convention

- **Stay organized**
- Find files faster because apparently spaces are bad for databases and it is better to use _
- The best advice I got was this  ["Far more important than a particular convention is being consistent. Pick a style, and stick with it."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7356/186165)

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

**An Example of what I am talking about**
 [image: Default Windows Save]

Comment: There is one extremely important misconception: There is no “windows file saving convention format”. That’s entirely up to the application!

Comment: I understand that, put if there was a way to hardcode that convention, it would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) you can get one step closer to what you need. I'm actually using this approach.

Here is sample set of hotkeys <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> through <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> which insert current date in various formats. This is just an example, you can customize what is inserted and even make it inserted immediately after the Save dialog is open (code for that is not included).

```
#F2::   ;Long date
    FormatTime, TimeString,, yyyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    Send %TimeString%
Return

#F3::   ;Short date
    FormatTime, TimeString,, yyyyy-MM-dd
    Send %TimeString%
Return

#F4::   ;Code date
    FormatTime, TimeString,, yyMMdd
    Send %TimeString%
Return

#F5::   ;Long date for filenames
    FormatTime, TimeString,, yyyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss
    Send %TimeString%
Return
```

Comment: Dude, this software is brilliant! Thanks so much!

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife – yes, it is, especially for productivity. E.g. it can expand typed stuff into sentence (e.g. `-btw` → `by the way`) or create keyboard shortcuts for everything (e.g. press `Alt`+`Shift`+`R` in your favourite productivity application to let it navigate through several menus and windows and open your frequently accessed report - before it took almost 10 seconds to do these actions manually). Worth checking the *Beginners* section on the AutoHotKey homepage.